# NLog global properties

Tags: c#, parameters, nlog

Using NLog is there any way to define global `LogEventInfo` properties for logs?
Using construction

```
var logEventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Trace, Log.Name, "Hello world");
logEventInfo.Properties["messageName"] = "MessageName2";
```

isn't suitable, because in big project everywhere using `Info(...)` and similar methods. But we need to add some parameters to watch them at `Gelf` logging without rewriting code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you looking for the global diagnostic context / mapped diagnostic context?

Set in your code:

```cs
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("prop1", "I'm scoped for all threads");
MappedDiagnosticsContext.Set("prop2", "I'm scoped per thread and child thread");
```

Usage in config:

```xml
${gdc:item=prop1}
${mdc:item=prop2}
```

See also https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/gdc-Layout-Renderer & https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/mdc-Layout-Renderer